# Ways to launch a batch file or .exe or .ps1 through Capybara

Tags: batch-file, selenium, cucumber, capybara

Problem : want to replace a file in wwwroot folder to change the user in web application

Setup :

> application sits at local host
>
> test setup : Cucumber + Capybara +Site Prism +Selenium webdriver

From cucumber step definition or say from any helper method  , i want launch batch file that swaps the file.

In Selenium we can use somethings like this  :

```
Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\http_IE8.exe"); 
or
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime.exec("file path of exe or .bat files");
```

I would like to  know :

1. Is there anything like this in capybara to launch files
2. How to call selenium functionalities in capybara/cucumber code (basically i am looking for format like `Selenium::webdriver::xx`)  , Say i want to use Process.start in cucumber steps ( what to inculde in *env.rb* and how to call in step definition file)

need directions , what to read to get this done .

Thanks

Pardon if there are any blunders in question or setup .I am just reading and trying . :)

I know that `Capybara` is web ui automation tool and not supposed to deal with things outside browser . I was just  thinking that there might be something to invoke or start batch or exe file

Comment: exec"C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\test.bat" is working fine for launching a batch file  from my setup in ruby(from cucumber steps ) . Will use  till someone gives there feedback on this  or i get a better solution or any other way .

Comment: Neither selenium nor capybara will launch windows processes like you are asking. Ruby can do that. Selenium and capybara are libraries used for test automation in ruby. Ruby runs it. Ruby can run a near infinite other things for you.